# How to call Magento 2 custom variables in phtml file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-variable

I have created custom varibles in "System -> Other Settings -> Custom Variables" for different store views.
How can i call them in phtml files for store views?

I am trying following code but its not working

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('storenumber');
$plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();

?>

<div class="h3"><?php echo $plain_value ?></div>
```

Comment: Please add system.xml file code in question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following worked for me.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$storenumber= $objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->setStoreId($storeID)->loadByCode('storenumber');
$storenumber_html = $storenumber->getHtmlValue();
$storenumber_plain = $storenumber->getPlainValue();
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the difference between my code and your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this below way :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

$objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->setStoreId($storeID)->loadByCode('your_custom_variable')->getHtmlValue(); // Return Html Value

$objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->setStoreId($storeID)->loadByCode('your_custom_variable')->getPlainValue(); // Return Plain Value
```

**Note : Don't use object manager directly. Use View Model or Block to get value.**

Comment: How can i call them multiple with Block (<?php echo $block->??(vairaiblename); ?>)?

Comment: You need to pass variable one by one as parameter in your block function.

Comment: Its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* I used custom variable on checkout success page */
namespace Vendor\Checkout\ViewModel;

use Magento\Variable\Model\Variable as CustomVariable;


class Success implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomVariable
     */
    protected CustomVariable $customVariable;

    /**
     * Your constructor.
     *
     * @param CustomVariable $customVariable
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomVariable $customVariable
    ) {
        $this->customVariable = $customVariable;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMyCoolUrl(): string
    {
        $url = $this->customVariable->loadByCode('your_code')->getValue();
        /* default is html - see vendor/magento/module-variable/Model/Variable.php */
        return !empty($url) ? $url : 'some_default_value';
    }
}

In template:
/** @var $viewModel Vendor\Checkout\ViewModel\Success */
<a href="<?= $viewModel->getMyCoolUrl(); ?>" class="foo">my link</a>
```